# Slide transitions when switching views (routes)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group, react-spring

Is there anybody who has experience with animating react-router-dom routes? My goal is to make slide animation and to make it slide forwards and backwards.

I’m asking because I’ve searched on stackoverflow, Google or even official react-router-dom or react-spring documentations and I really can’t find working solution for this.

Everything I’ve found was outdated or not working and I can’t find any tutorial. Is there anybody who can give me some advices or share some tutorial?

I’m asking in advance and not posting any code now because I’ll work on that tomorrow. So some tips ,tricks and recommendations will be handy. (Working codesandbox link will be the best so I can see how it really works).

Thanks

Comment: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router/

Comment: Thanks for an advice ! Do you have experience with it? I mean if I have problems with functionality can you please give me an advice with it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on level up tutorials.
https://www.leveluptutorials.com/tutorials/animating-react
video #12

And there are a couple of examples on codesandbox too.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jp1wr1867w

this one to prevent scrollbars:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-page-transition-example-to-prevent-scrollbar-8uckc?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Thanks for your advice . Currently I’ve tried approach which @jean182 recommended me in comments section. It seems to work but some parts are little bit unclear to me . I have to go to work now, but later i will take a look at this too. If i encounter some problem will you be that kind and try to help me with something ? Thanks again. :)